# Send a value from a cookie to a script

Tags: javascript

A user input form on my site sends values to a script located on a different server:

`<form action="https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/" method="post" name="MyForm" onsubmit="return myFunction();">` etc.

I am recreating that form with a modified functionality. Instead of sending the form values directly, I save them in a cookie, and only then, when a certain event happens, I want to send input values **from that cookie** to the script located at the url provided as the value for action attribute.

Something like this:

```
on event {
 // send cookie value to https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/ using "post" method;
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need to use some cookie functions to store the values in cookie(s) and then access the input values you have saved in those cookie(s). Some cookie functions with explanation how to use them are here: http://www.codelib.net/javascript/cookies.html

Then you will need to have a way of sending the data across domains. To do that I suggest that you use a form containing a hidden field and then submit that form to the other server.

Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/">
<input type="hidden" id="hiddendata" name="data" />
</form>

<script>
function onEvent() { /* call this function when your desired event happens */
  var cookiedata = readCookie('cookiename');
  var datafield = document.getElementById('hiddendata');
  datafield.value = cookiedata;
  datafield.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Note that I suggest you have the program at `formprocessor` return `204 No Content` as its HTTP status code so that the document itself is not reset. Otherwise the browser will replace the current page with the contents of `https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/` after the data is submitted. This is the a way of doing AJAX that does not block cross-domain requests.

The following method will only work if you are content with using `GET` requests to send the data to the server.

You can set the `src` attribute of included elements on the page, like an `img` element, to a URL like this (initial image is from http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1x1.png)

```
<img id="hiddenimage" width="1" height="1" src="1x1.png" />

<script>
function onEvent() { /* call this function when your desired event happens */
  var cookiedata = readCookie('cookiename');
  var dataimage  = document.getElementById('hiddenimage');
  dataimage.src = 'https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/?data=' + encodeURIComponent(cookiedata);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect, @Joseph. Could you please explain a little more in detail how the program should return 204 No Content as its HTTP status code, please?

Comment: I answered your question and also edited my answer, and then somehow it duplicated my post!! Look below for the answer to your question about 204 No Content.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to use some cookie functions to store the values in cookie(s) and then access the input values you have saved in those cookie(s). Some cookie functions with explanation how to use them are here: http://www.codelib.net/javascript/cookies.html

Then you will need to have a way of sending the data across domains. To do that I suggest that you use a form containing a hidden field and then submit that form to the other server.

Like this:

```
<script>
function onEvent() { /* call this function when your desired event happens */
  var cookiedata = readCookie('cookiename');
  var datafield = document.getElementById('hiddendata');
  datafield.value = cookiedata;
  datafield.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Note that I suggest you have the program return 204 No Content as its HTTP status code so that the document itself is not reset. Otherwise the browser will replace the current page with the contents of `https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/` after the data is submitted. This is the a way of doing AJAX that does not block cross-domain requests.

I am about to describe another way of sending cross-domain requests without submitting a form... please wait.

The following method will only work if you are content with using `GET` requests to send the data to the server.

You can set the `src` attribute of included elements on the page, like an `img` element, to a URL like this (initial image is from http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1x1.png)

```
<img id="hiddenimage" width="1" height="1" src="1x1.png" />

<script>
function onEvent() { /* call this function when your desired event happens */
  var cookiedata = readCookie('cookiename');
  var dataimage  = document.getElementById('hiddenimage');
  dataimage.src = 'https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/?data=' + encodeURIComponent(cookiedata);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect, @Joseph. Could you please explain a little more in detail how the program should return 204 No Content as its HTTP status code, please?

Comment: @KeithRules Yes, the first line of the response should be HTTP/1.1 204 No Content rather than HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: Thank you, @Joseph! Another question – if I use something like `window.location = myownpage.html` immediately after `form.submit();` – would that work as a viable alternative to setting the response to 204 in the file on the server?

Comment: @KeithRules No, that would not work unless you are lucky. You could make a named iframe in your document and set the target of the form to be that iframe. When the form was submitted, it would load the results into the iframe, but then your scripts would no longer have any control over that iframe since it would be on a different domain. You could experiment starting with a very small iframe, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values set in the cookie by using "document.cookie".

Update:

```
var cookievalue= document.cookie;
var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="https://example.com/path?value="+cookievalue;
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thank you, @Balaji. I appreciate this suggestion. That's not really what I asked about, though. What I want to figure out is how to send the value from a cookie to a script hosted elsewhere. Would be grateful for your input on that.

Comment: You can use ajax to send cookie value.

Comment: That sounds like a step in the right direction, @Balaji... but could you please teach me how to do that?

Comment: In ordinary circumstances, you cannot use ajax to send the cookie value to another server. Permission is denied for cross-domain ajax requests.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you, @Joseph. In your opinion, what would be the correct way to approach the task that I'm facing?

Comment: If you have access to the server then you can enable "cors" to do cross domain request. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I do not have access to that server, @BalajiSivanath.

Answer (score 0):

The answer kind of depends on how the script that's accepting the values is set up. For storing and retrieving the values, balaji's suggestion is good enough. The plugin located [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) makes storing and retrieving values to/from cookies very easy.

So, for e.g. if the function you are sending the values to is something like this:

```
public void myFunction(firstValue, secondValue){
   // logic here
}
```

then the way you'd send the values is something like this:

```
https://mycompany.formprocessor.com/script/firstValue="value_from_cookie"?secondValue="value_from_cookie"
```